# Check if function exists on a page

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to check if a certain javascript (if you know what kind of script your looking for) is active on a url using PHP ? and if so how?

Comment: Fetch by this URL, check the contents.

Comment: Why was the [tag:PHP] tag removed from this question? Maybe the OP wants to check this using PHP?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Actually that was exactly what i wanted!.

Comment: The problem here is, that when you get the document itself it's not guaranteed, that the JavaScript function/part you're looking for is in this document. Maybe it's in an external JavaScript file. So you may have to get all files related to this document and check them too. What is it exactly what you're searching for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether a function is on the page, without executing the function.

```
if (functionName) {
    // this function exists on this page
    // feel free to call it
    functionName();
}
```

Note: This will only work with function that have names.

Comment: +1, but make sure that `functionName` is actually a function.

Comment: so: $data = file_get_contents('www.example.com'); and then your part?

Comment: The answer is JavaScript based. So it works only if you execute this on the page itself. It doesn't work when fetching the content with PHP.